# Linq query with left join and group

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm unable to convert this SQL query into a working linq statement

`select sum(cena), id_auta, max(servis) 
from dt_poruchy left outer join mt_auta on dt_poruchy.id_auta=mt_auta.id

where dt_poruchy.servis>=3 group by id_auta;`

I tryed something like this but i cant handle the select statement

```
   var auta = from a in MtAuta.FindAll()
                   join p in DtPoruchy.FindAll() on a equals p.MtAuta into ap
                   from ap2 in ap.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where ap2.SERVIS >= 3
                   group ap2 by ap2.ID into grouped
                   select new {
```

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached this solution (supposing "cena" belongs to `MtAuta.FindAll()`):

```
        var auta = from e in
                       (from a in DtPoruchy.FindAll()
                        where a.SERVIS >= 3
                        join p in MtAuta.FindAll() on a.MtAuta equals p.Id into ap
                        from ap2 in ap.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            Cena = ap.cena,
                            IdAuta = a.MtAuta,
                            Servis = a.servis
                        })
                   group e by e.IdAuta into g
                   select new
                   {
                       Cena = g.Sum(e => e.cena),
                       IdAuta = g.Key,
                       Servis = g.Max(e => e.servis)
                   };
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited information provided (which tables are certain fields from?), here is what I came up with.

```
var auta = from a in MtAuta.FindAll()
           let p = a.DtPoruchys.Where(s => s.SERVIS >= 3)
           select new
           {
               Id = a.Id,
               CenaSum = p.Sum(c => c.Cena),
               Servis = p.Max(s => s.SERVIS)
           };
```

Comment: Let me know if I made any incorrect assumptions, and I'll make sure to update my answer!

Comment: i'm sorry for my incoplete definition.

The MtAuta is the master table (containing DtPoruchy) and DtPoruchy is the slave table containing the  CENA,SERVIS and ID_AUTA fields.

Comment: Besides the capitalization in my answer, does this work for you? Are you using LinqToSql, and if so, are your relationships set up properly? It appeared so, as you had `p.MtAuta` in your question, but it might be good to confirm.

Comment: actually i'm not using Linq to SQL but Linq to NHibernate. Your answer didn't work for me. And the class DtPoruchy has a reference to the MtAuto. The statement p.MtAuta is correct.

Comment: I would imagine a simpler solution may exist (similar to mine), but I haven't played with Linq to NHibernate yet, so I don't know what it is :(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which table cena and servis are coming from but to create grouped sum you do something like.

```
select new { Sum = grouped.Sum( x => x.cena ) }
```

and to get max

```
select new { Max = grouped.Group.Max( x => x.servis ) }
```

Here is a good reference for you.

- [MSDN - 101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your solution little bit and i got it working like this:

```
var auta = from jo in
                       (
                           from a in MtAuta.FindAll()
                           join p in DtPoruchy.FindAll() on a equals p.MtAuta into ap
                           from ap2 in ap.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where ap2.SERVIS >= 3
                           select new
                           {
                               Cena = ap2.CENA,
                               Idauto = ap2.ID_AUTA,
                               Servis = ap2.SERVIS
                           }
                       )
                   group jo by jo.Idauto into g
                   select new
                   {
                       Cena = g.Sum(jo => jo.Cena),
                       IdAuto = g.Key,
                       Servis = g.Max(jo => jo.Servis)
                   };
```

I just curious if this is the best solution?

Comment: It's unlikely that you need anything remotely this complicated. Check out Ryan's answer.